# Clearing old input values?

Tags: laravel

I have a create form. If the user exists I redirect in the Form Request:

```
$this->redirect = route('user.edit', $id);
```

The user is redirected to the edit form.

Yet, the old values from the original create form are passed to the edit form. I do not wish this to happen.

How can old input values be cleared?

Comment: Can you post your edit form?

Comment: @Unflux - Edit form does echo old output for values. It's required for errors on the edit form itself.

Comment: You could try doing this before redirecting back:

`$request->session()->forget('_old_input');`